# where the logs are stored if logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have set `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

and using it like below:

```
def get_token(self, username, password):
        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
        logging.info("%s" % self.base_url)
        try:
            response = requests.post(self.base_url, auth=auth, verify=False)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("%s" % str(e))
```

in which directory should i see the logs ?

Comment: Did you actually configure the logs to go to a file? If not, they're not getting stored at all.

Comment: no. I have not... should i use basicConfig ?

Answer (score 2):

you can specify two outputs: console (stream) and file output:

```
settings_folder = os.path.join(os.environ["APPDATA"], "my_app")
logging_file = os.path.join(settings_folder, "app.log")

if not os.path.isdir(settings_folder):
    os.mkdir(settings_folder)

# add logging to console and log file
logging.basicConfig(filename=logging_file, format='%(asctime)s (%(levelname)s) %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    datefmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Comment: thanks Beliaev, loggin.basicConfig funciton should be under 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
?

Comment: @Gaurav, in any place where you need to initialize logging.